# Comparing two ranges in Excel

Tags: string, excel, range

I'm having a problem creating a function in Excel on what I think is an array.  I do not have much experience with arrays and have tried Google but haven't found an example to apply to my situation.

Problem:

Row 1 (through 1000) contain a user with his immediate leadership going up 6 users deep.  These are all text values.  All leaders for a specific row are unique.

I have a separate column (Column M) which is a list of users that I want to compare against each row.  I want to compare Column M to the Row 1 users and if there is a match, return the matched name.

Example

```
row 1 | user1 | John  | Rick | Mary | Paul | Jim | {matched leader goes here - Mary}

row 2 | user2 | Rick  | Mary | Paul | Jim  | Ann | {matched leader goes here - Mary}

row 3 | user3 | Terry | John | Rick | Mary | Paul | {matched leader goes here - Mary}

row 4 | user3 | Sylvia | Steve | Tom | Eric | Lorriaine| {matched leader goes here - Lorraine}
```

Column M (VP List)

```
 - Mary
 - Ken
 - Lorraine
```

I have tried VLOOKUP, but my lookup_value is range (column M) and I wasn't sure how to manage that.  I started a Nested IF, but I have to manage there is a more straightforward way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you could include a small example of how your data looks.

Comment: Added some data, let me now if this helps.  Basically the users will be in varying levels of a leadership hierarchy.  The VP list I'm comparing it to would only appear once in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit wordy, but should do the job.

Formula for cell G1 (which can be copied down into G2..G1000)

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,$M:$M,1,0))
&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(B1,$M:$M,1,0))
&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(C1,$M:$M,1,0))
&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(D1,$M:$M,1,0))
&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(E1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(E1,$M:$M,1,0))
&IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F1,$M:$M,1,0)),"",VLOOKUP(F1,$M:$M,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure makes any data processing difficult. I recommend the following:

```
ROW NO.| USER  | PERSON | LEADER?
row 1  | user1 | John   | 0
row 2  | user1 | Rick   | 0
row 3  | user1 | Mary   | 1
row 4  | user2 | Rick   | 0
row 5  | user2 | Mary   | 1
```

1. You can convert your original data structure (7 columns) to the above one (2 columns - user, person) easily
2. And you can add the third column indicating if that person is a leader (Mary => 1)
3. Finally it will be easy to lookup the leader

Note that using this data structure, all formula will be simple and straightforward. It is also easy for you to create different kinds of report.

I understand that visually the 7-column structure looks more appealing, however it is a trade-off for the data processing ability. Thus I suggest you convert the 7-column structure to a 2-column one with simple formula first. In this way you can benefit from both structures.